# angular 5 material change custom component theme

Tags: angular, themes, angular5, angular-material2

i am struggling with themes very hard. my requirement is to change the theme on the fly. for default component it seems to work fine. but for custom components i m failing to understand. Here is the implementation:

i have a **styles.scss**

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

.widget-para-title {
    font-size: small;
    margin-top:10px;
    color:#4A90E2;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
}
```

** theme.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$custom-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey,500);
$custom-accent:  mat-palette($mat-lime, 100);
$custom-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$custom-theme: mat-light-theme($custom-primary, $custom-accent, $custom-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);


//Orange theme
$ora-primary: mat-palette($mat-orange, 800);
$ora-accent:  mat-palette($mat-grey, 200);
$ora-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$ora-theme: mat-light-theme($ora-primary, $ora-accent);

.orange-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($ora-theme);
}


//green theme
$green-primary: mat-palette($mat-green, 800);
$green-accent:  mat-palette($mat-grey, 200);
$green-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$green-theme: mat-light-theme($green-primary, $green-accent);

.green-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($green-theme);
}
```

i am using the below to change theme on the fly
**app.component.ts**

```
setTheme(theme:string){
      //var theme='green-theme'
      this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(theme);
      this.componentCssClass = theme;
  }
```

The thing where i am stuck is that in the styles.css the color is currently hardcoded which should be same as the value of primary color of the current theme. so what change do i need to make in the above code to get it working?

Comment: Can you try mixins?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best practice is to create a mixin for each component you want to theme.

```
@mixin widget-theme($theme) {
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);

  .widget-para-title {
      color: mat-color($primary);
      // other styles
    }
  }

@include widget-theme($custom-theme);

.green-theme {
   @include widget-theme($green-theme);
 }

.ora-theme {
   @include widget-theme($ora-theme);
 }
```

Read more about [theming your own components](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

Comment: so will  include widget-theme($green-theme); be additional line under .green-theme and .ora-theme  where i already have include angular-material-theme($green-theme); ? does the order matter ?